# Why it need to be parsing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parsing, razor, html-helper

I have question about parsing in Html helper :

I have sth like:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.News)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.gdt_title, "News", "News", new { lang = ViewBag.Lang, page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, id = item.gdt_id }, null)
}
```

so then I have an error:

`'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'ActionLink' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.`

I solve it with manualy parse first parametr to string:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.News)
{
    @Html.ActionLink((String)item.gdt_title, "News", "News", new { lang = ViewBag.Lang, page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, id = item.gdt_id }, null)
}
```

But I don't know why it happen.

Can somebody explain it?

Comment: What you have is done with the `(String)item.gdt_title` construct is called casting not parsing. And the exception message describes what is the problem: `Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched`. `Html.ActionLink` is an extension method and `ViewBag.News` is dynamic that's why you need the cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Using ViewBag/ViewData is bad practice.*

You are using dynamic model, and `item.gdt_title` is dynamic. As the exception says,

> Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched

You should be using strongly typed view models. Something like this

```
public class NewsViewModel
{
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public List<NewsItem> News { get; set; }
}

public class NewsItem
{
     public string gdt_id { get; set; }
     public string gdt_title { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
public ActionResult News()
{
     NewsViewModel news = new NewsViewModel();
     news.News = LoadNews();

     return View(news);
}
```

view

```
@model NewsViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.News)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.gdt_title, "News", "News", new { lang = Model.Lang, page = Model.CurrentPage, id = item.gdt_id }, null)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my model and controller view similar but I return different data as view result. But thanks a lot for good practice advice :)